# $\int_0^x (x-t)^2g(t)\,dt$ has a local minimum if $g(0) = 0$ and $g'(0) > 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

Let $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function
such that $g(0)=0$ and $g'(0)>0$.

Consider the function $$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^x (x-t)^2g(t)\,dt$$

Prove that $f$ has a local minimum at $x=0$.

So far, I can find a formula of derivative of $f$ $$f'(x)=\int_0^x(x-t)g(t)\,dt$$ without using any information about $g$. How can we apply the condition about $g$ to show $f$ has a local minimum at $x=0$?

Comment: The condition on $g$ yields that the first, second, third derivatives at $0$ are $0$ but the fourth derivative is positive, I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It follows from $g(0) = 0$ and $g'(0)>0$ that there is a $a > 0$ such that $g$ is strictly negative on $(-a, 0)$ and $g$ is strictly positive on $(0, a)$.

Use this to show that $f$ is strictly positive on $(-a, 0)$ and on $(0, a)$, so that $f(0) = 0$ is a local minimum.

Comment: Could you please explain more why such $a$ exist? Does it follows from some definition or theorem?

Comment: @kompaui: It follows directly from the definition of the limit. You have $g'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{g(x)}{x} > 0$, therefore $\frac{g(x)}{x}$ is positive in some $(-a, a) \setminus \{ 0 \}$.

Comment: arhhhhh. Thank you very much. It is all clear now.

Comment: @kompaui: If this answered your question, then you should also click on the green checkmark near the top left of this answer. This "accepts" the answer and marks to the website and others that your query has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It should be clear that

$$ f'(0)=0.$$

Show that $f$ is twice differentiable and

$$f''(x)= \int_0^xg(t)dt.$$

This shows that $f'''$ exists and

$$f'''(x)=g(x).$$

Hence $f^{(4)}$ exists and $f^{(4)}(x)=g'(x).$

Then we have

$$f'(0)=f''(0)=f'''(0)=0$$

and

$$ f^{(4)}(0)=g'(0)>0.$$

Answer (score 0):

$f'(x)=\int_0^x(x-t)g(t)dt>0$ for $x$ positive and sufficiently small (because $g(0)=0, g'(0) >0$ implies that $g$ is positive in some right neighborhood of $0$). Similarly, $f'(x) <0$  for $x$ negative and sufficiently small. These two facts together with the fact that $f(0)=0$ imply that $f$ has local minimum at $0$.  [Near $0$,  $f$ is increasing to the right of $0$ and decreasing to the left of $0$].